# Regex to match only one sentence

Tags: php, regex

Is there a regular expression in PHP to match only one sentence. For example a sentence starting with a capital letter and ending with `.`, `!` or `?`.

```
preg_match(/regex here/g, $string, $matches);
```

And sometimes abbreviations is used so words with 2 characters or less must not end the sentence if it's followed by an `.`.

Comment: It's easy to come up with counter-examples where your definition of sentence is incorrect.  It goes bam! and there you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `a sentence starting with a capital letter and ending with ., ! or ?`

You can use:

```
preg_match('/[A-Z].*?[.!?]/s', $string, $matches);
```

Details:

- `[A-Z]   - To match any capital letter`
- `.*?  - Match a string of 0 or more characters (non greedy)`
- `[.!?]/ - Match one of . OR ! OR ?`
- `/s` - Make dot match newlines as well

Comment: Should probably be `[.!?]` under the definition provided .. and of course it's very easy to break such a construct: "Mr. Henry yelled 'I like apples!' while he danced."

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `["'“]?([A-Z]((?!([A-Za-z]{2,}|\d+)[.?!]+["']?\s+["']?[A-Z]).)*)(((Mr|Ms|Mrs|Dr|Capt|Col)\.\s+((?!\w{2,}[.?!]['"]?\s+["']?[A-Z]).)*)?)*((?![.?!]["']?\s+["']?[A-Z]).)*[.?!]+["'”]?`

Source: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?779582-Choose-whole-sentences-and-ONLY-whole-sentences-RELIABLY-with-regex

Comment: This is also very breakable. The title is very misleading with the "REALIABLY".